# Trying to understand record_response block at an ActiveRestClient object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code in `model` class.

```
class Article < ActiveRestClient::Base
  record_response do |url, response|
    File.open(url.parameterize, "w") do |f|
      f << response.body
    end
  end
end
```

Couple of questions:

1. Where does the url and response come from?.
2. `File.open(url.parameterize)` What File does it open/create?
3. `f << response.body` does it push response.body to the file?.

Comment: The `url` comes from the `response` it looks like, which the `response` looks like it comes from `ActiveRestClient::Base`.  `File.open` opens the file passed in as the `url`. Yes `f << response.body` adds it to the file.